# Better way to enable RBS type checking in Rspec tests?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rbs

I'm incrementally adding RBS type signatures to my Ruby (not Rails) project.  The project contains a `Rakefile` for running tests manually, but also a `Guardfile` for running tests when files change.

For that reason I've added the RBS setup to `spec_helper.rb`, to avoid having to duplicate it in both `Rakefile` and `Guardfile`.

```
# spec_helper.rb
ENV['RBS_TEST_TARGET'] ||= 'MyModule::*'
require 'rbs/test/setup'
```

This works as expected - the type signatures are verified regardless of what winds up running the specs.  It feels like a bit of a hack, though; is there a better or even a more idiomatic way of doing this?